# Set category class as delegate in parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` named `EditNoteViewController_iPad` and I have create a category for this class `EditNoteViewController_iPad (Operation)`.

This category contain some delegate methods.

My setDelegate method is in EditNoteViewController_iPad Which I can not transfer to category class.

Now I am getting a warning on setDelegate method like follow:

```
Sending 'EditNoteViewController_iPad *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<ZNVideoViewDelegate>'
```

Line That show warning in `EditNoteViewController_iPad` :

```
[Video setDelegate:self];
```

How can I remove This warning?

My project is working fine. I just want to remove this warning.

Comment: You will need to show more code. e.g. the protocol you are trying to conform to, etc...

Comment: Protocol is user define. as u can see in warning its name is ZNVideoViewDelegate.

Comment: And set statement is very simple [Video setDelegate:self];

Comment: Yes, that tells me exactly nothing. The error message suggests that the protocol accepts a certain type of object...

Comment: You want to see protocol definition? I dont think there is any problem because it is working very fine without category. But If u want than tell me I can Put That also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare that your `EditNoteViewController_iPad` class conforms to the `ZNVideoViewDelegate` protocol. Your `@interface` in the header should look similar to this:

```
@interface EditNoteViewController_iPad : UIViewController <ZNVideoViewDelegate>
{...}                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*Edit*: If you implemented the protocol in a category, you need to import that category's header in the `.m` file where you set the delegate, so that the compiler knows that the class conforms to the protocol.

Comment: Thanks to reply. Because I I have implemented all delegate method in category class so I have to use < ZNVideoViewDelegate> in EditNoteViewController_iPad (Operation) file instead of EditNoteViewController_iPad.h file.

Comment: And if I use <ZNVideoViewDelegate> in EditNoteViewController_iPad It remove this warning and give other warning "Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class"

Comment: Then you need to import the header of the category where you set the delegate.

Comment: You mean #import "EditNoteViewController_iPad+Operation.h"?

Comment: I have put #import "EditNoteViewController_iPad+Operation.h" in "EditNoteViewController_iPad.h" and it give error because of import cycle. Than I put it on "EditNoteViewController_iPad.m" and it remove all warning. Now perfect. Edit your answer I will accept it. Thank you so much.